# Eclipse Oxygen does not connecting with VSS

Tags: eclipse-plugin, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying connecting with VSS in Eclipse Oxygen it is throwing an error org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.OleInitialize(I)I. How to resolve it. can anybody help me please.

Comment: Can you described the steps how you got the [OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) issue? OLE is to show documents inside of Eclipse on Windows. How is this related to VSS? If you use 64 bit Windows, that might be caused by 32 bit (Java+Eclipse) vs. 64 bit (Windows application to show document via OLE).

Comment: Thank you @howlger I got solution for above problem in eclipse oxygen 64 bit vss plugin is not support if you want connect with vss you must use eclipse and jre must be 32 bit.

Comment: So it was exactly the other way around as I guessed. For others facing the same issue a self-answer might be helpful.